# Geometric intuition behind inverse matrix restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

We know that for an invertible matrix $A$, $A^{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{adj}(A)}{\det{(A)}}$. We can see algebraically that this is undefined when $\det(A)=0$, but it is cryptic what this means geometrically. Is the following intuition valid? **This is not meant to be rigorous.**

Define a matrix $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (e.g. mapping 3D space onto the X-Y plane). Because this maps the $n$-dimensional parallelepiped such that it does not occupy the $n$-th dimension, it's $n$-dimensional "volume" is $0$. Hence, $\det(A)=0$. Now, define another matrix $T:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that maps the $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped such that it coincides with the parallelepiped that $A$ acted on. When viewing in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ space, $A$ and $T$ are indistinguishable, so there is ambiguity as to what the initial state was. Therefore, $A^{-1}$ is undefined. $\blacksquare$

EDIT: 3Blue1Brown articulates this point better than I do. I just found this. I was trying to say that essentially, if you squish space down into a smaller dimension, there is no way to distinguish squishing higher dimensional space and transforming space of the same dimension. There is ambiguity as to what the initial state was, so $A$ is not a bijection.
https://youtu.be/uQhTuRlWMxw?t=403

Comment: For a "matrix" $A:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-1}$, does $\det A$ make sense?

Comment: $\det A$ is the volume of the image of the unit $n$-cube under $A$.  If $A$ is non-singular the image is an $n$-dimensional polytope with non-zero volume.  So, if $\det A=0$, $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Could it work if $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$? For example, mapping the unit cube to the X-Y plane? Would that still be valid, or would $A$ still be $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Pendronator We would still say that $A$ represents a map $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$, but the map fails to be onto (surjective)

Comment: @Pendronator It would help if we could nail down exactly what it is that you're trying to explain geometrically. Would you say that you're trying to find an argument that if $\det(A) = 0$, then $A^{-1}$ does not exist?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. My argument is that you can map (I'll use 3D and 2D space as an example) 3D space onto the X-Y plane so that $\det(A)$ is $0$. However, you can also map 2D space onto the same orientation such that the two modified coordinate systems coincide. Because they're indistinguishable, there's ambiguity as to the initial state, so $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I found that 3Blue1Brown articulates my point better than I do. https://youtu.be/uQhTuRlWMxw?t=403

Comment: Ultimately, the issue is that a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ gives rise to a $2 \times 3$ matrix (or a $3 \times 2$ matrix, if you prefer), hence there is no notion of determinant. Determinant only makes sense for square ($n \times n$) matrices.

Comment: @Carlo I changed the question. The matrix $A$ is now $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. I meant that $A$ maps 3D space to the X-Y plane, but it is still in 3D space. Hence, all points look like (x, y, 0).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "Now, define another matrix $T:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that maps the $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped such that it coincides with the parallelepiped that $A$ acted on."

That said, you seem to have already accepted that if $\det(A) = 0$, then the image of $A$ is at most $(n-1)$-dimensional (i.e. $A$ fails to be surjective/onto). From this alone, it is clear that $A$ cannot have an inverse.  After all: for any $b \in \Bbb R^n$, $x = A^{-1}b$ is supposed to satisfy $T(x) = b$. However, if $b$ lies outside the "squished" subspace of outputs from $A$, then we can never have $T(x) = b$.

---

Another geometric argument: note that $|\det(A)|$ is the "volume stretch factor" of the transformation associated with $A$. It follows that for $A,B$, we have $|\det(AB)| = |\det(A)| \cdot |\det(B)|$.  Now, because the identity mapping has a stretch factor of $1$ and $AA^{-1} = I$, it follows that $|\det(A)|\cdot |\det(A^{-1})| = 1$.

So, if $\det(A) = 0$, then whatever the inverse $A^{-1}$ is would have to satisfy $0 \cdot |\det(A^{-1})| = 1$, but that's impossible.

Comment: By the first part, I meant that $T$ maps the X-Y plane such that the image of the X-Y plane under $T$ is indistinguishable from the image of 3D space under $A$.

Comment: @Pendronator Fine, but how do you know that this is the case? How do you show that there is an X-Y plane inside the domain that gets mapped onto the image?

Comment: I was just using 3D and 2D space as an example.

Comment: My point is, whatever the dimensionality, how do you find the subspace in the domain that gets faithfully mapped to the image, or at least show/argue that such a subspace exists?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe we could define $T$ as the projection of $A$ onto $(n-1)$-dimensional space? I don't have a ton of experience in this stuff.